# Generate subcatchment starting from a DTM

Tags: qgis, dem, watershed

I would like to know if there is a plug-in in Quantum GIS, which can help me to generate subcatchments starting from a DTM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at the Processing framework searching for catchment or watershed in the toolbox.

[image: Processing]

Also check the Processing manual:

https://github.com/volaya/Processing-manual/blob/foss4g_ws/sphinx/source/modeler_hydro.rst

https://github.com/volaya/Processing-manual/tree/foss4g_ws/sphinx/source

Comment: >>Simbamangu, whuber
The question 'might' be a dublicate but the answer is not. Since this is not a religious question, I can not see any trouble in having different answers to the same question.